# Constrained infinity norm minimization

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I have a problem like this:

$$\min_x |Ax|_\infty  \text{ s.t. } \sum_i x_i = c$$

That is, I want to find the vector $x$ whose elements sum to a constant $c$ that minimized the infinity norm of $Ax$.

Does this problem have a particular name? I've been unable to find a function to do something like this in things like lpsolve, glpk, etc. Can anyone suggest a c/c++ solver for this problem?

Comment: Minimizing $\lVert Ax\rVert_\infty$ is equivalent to minimizing $y$ subject to $-y\le(Ax)_i\le y$ for all $i$. This makes it a linear programming problem in $n+1$ variables.

Comment: There is a mathematica command that will do this for you. See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/LinearAlgebra/7.3.html).

Comment: @AlexBecker I came across that, but didn't follow. In equation 53, what is 'e'? (Repeated here, that website says: Minimizing the Infinity-norm is similar to minimizing the 1-norm. It involves finding the value of that minimizes the following.

Min \|Ax-b\|_\infty

This is done by forming new variables and finding the minimum.

Min z s.t. ze \geq Ax-b, ze \geq -(Ax-b)
)

Which actually I think is exactly what Rahul just said?

Comment: Rahul Why n+1 variables? Isn't y the same dimension as the original x? And isn't that inequality constraint you wrote just equal to y >= Ax? (and is it supposed to be y_i >= (Ax)_i ?)

Comment: Minimizing $\max |z_i|$ is equivalent to minimizing $y$ such that $y \geq |z_i|$, which in turn is equivalent to $ -y \leq z_i \leq y$. In this case we have $Ax = z$. To answer your questions, $y$ is a scalar, so we could also write it as $-y\mathbf{1} \leq Ax \leq y\mathbf{1}$

Comment: @DavidDoria I'm not quite sure what 'e' is. But the process they're describing is the same as Rahul's.

Comment: Rahul Narain Is there a name for this or somewhere I can read more about why it works?

Comment: @RossB. Also, I don't know the x's (that's what I'm trying to minimize), so how do I add those as constraints to a solver?

Comment: It worked, thanks all! I've added an answer - if anyone wants to claim it I'd be happy to check the Accept check mark :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem can be restated as

$$\min y \\ s.t. \quad y \geq |Ax|_i \\ \quad \sum_i x_i = c$$

To provide this form to a solver (e.g. lpsolve), we can rewrite the constraint as

$$\min y \\s.t. \quad -y \leq (Ax)_i \leq y, \ i = 1, \dots, m, \\ \quad \sum_i x_i = c$$

that is,

$$\min y 
\\ s.t. -y \leq (Ax)_1 \leq y\\
\quad -y \leq (Ax)_2 \leq y\\
\dots\\
\quad -y \leq (Ax)_m \leq y.\\ 
\quad \sum_i x_i = c
$$

This form actually means that there are N+1 variables ($y \in \mathbb{R}$ and the original $x$'s).

Comment: You need to reverse the sign of inequalities. They should be $y\leq |Ax|_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Why? Doesn't the discussion show y >= Ax everywhere?

Comment: when $y\geq |x|$ this means either $y\leq -x$ or $y\geq x$. For $y$ to lie within $x$ and $-x$, $y\leq |x|$.