# Calculation of minimum infinity norm subject to L1 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, matlab

Can somebody tell me how to evaluate the following in MATLAB or any other programming language?

\begin{equation}
\min_{x \in \partial \|w\|_1} \| x+y\|_\infty  
\end{equation}
$x,w,y \in R^n$. $w,y$ is known to us.  My concern is that there are many subgradients of $\|w\|_1$. Which one to choose and how? I want the calculation in $O(n)$ flops.

Another way to put the question is: choose a subgradient from subdifferential set of L1 norm that mimimizes $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. Correct me if I interpreted the question wrongly.
Thanks.

Comment: Which is that of $\partial \|w\|_1$?

Comment: subgradient set of L1 norm.

Comment: can you give a precise description of $\partial \|w\|_1$? Also I guess that $w$ is known too, right?

Comment: As I said above, that is subdifferential set of L1 norm. see page 5 https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/01-subgradients_notes.pdf. $w$ is clearly known.

Comment: @chandresh I understood that it was the subdifferential. But my point is that since subdifferential of the $1$-norm is known, I think you should give a precise description of this set in order to higher chance to get an answer. By the way, $\partial \|w\|_1$ contains only $1$ point for almost every $w$.

Comment: A good expression is given for example here in page 5: https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/01-subgradients_notes.pdf

Comment: @Surb. If I already take $\partial \|w\|_1$ to just contain only one point then there is nothing to minimize. I mean I need to figure out minimum of $\max(|x_i+y_i|)$ for all $i$. I was thinking problem from more complex POV, That is, subgdifferentail set contains many subgradients. First I have to choose one of them and then minimise it. Thanks

Comment: .... I'm not sure you get my point. Anyway... what have you tried?

Comment: @Surb, If I fix $x$ (that is I chosen my subgradient), I can minimize $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ by converting it into LP problem as here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407881/constrained-infinity-norm-minimization

Comment: The whole deal here is to calculate the sub-gradient (use properties). Then the optimization can be rewritten as LP.

Comment: @A.G. "The whole deal here is to calculate the sub-gradient" exactly but OP seems not willing to do it... "Then the optimization can be rewritten as LP" might be although it looks to me that the solution can be written directly in terms of the entries of $w$ and $y$. Basically, for every $i$ such that $w_i=0$ you may choose $x_i\in\{\pm 1\}$ since you want to to minimize $|x_i+y_i|$ the choice you do depends on the sign of $y_i$.

Comment: It can't, in fact be written as an LP, since the subgradient is discrete-valued.

Comment: To make it more clear, it is a constrained problem. The constrain set is sub-differential set of $L1$ norm upon which I want to minimize $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the soft thresholding operation. The subgradient of $|w|$, where $w$ is a scalar, is
$$\partial |w| \triangleq \begin{cases}\{1\} & w > 0 \\ [-1,1] & w = 0 \\ \{-1\} & w < 0 \end{cases}$$
Therefore, to minimize $|x+y|$, we need to choose the value of $x$ closest to $-y$, but not exceeding $1$:
$$\begin{aligned}\min_{x\in\partial |w|} |x+y| &= \begin{cases} -y-1 & y < -1 \\ 0 & -1\leq y \leq 1 \\ y - 1 & y > 1 \end{cases} \\&= \max\{|y|-1,0\}\end{aligned}$$
For the vector case you simply apply this elementwise:
$$\min_{x\in\partial\|w\|_1} \|x+y\|_\infty = \sum_i \max\{|y_i|-1,0\}$$
The minimizing $x$ and $x+y$ is
$$x_i = -\mathop{\textrm{sgn}}(y_i) \min\{|y_i|,1\}, \quad i=1,2,\dots, n$$
$$x_i+y_i = \mathop{\textrm{sgn}}(y_i) \max\{|y_i|-1,0\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: to calculate the subgradienet for $f(w)=\|w\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^n|w_k|$, use three facts:

1. $f(w)=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(w)$, $f_k$ convex $\Rightarrow$ $\partial f(w)=\sum_{k=1}^n\partial f_k(w)$.
2. $f(z)=\max_{1\le k\le n}f_k(z)$, $f_k$ convex and differentiable $\Rightarrow$ 
   $$
   \partial f(z)=\text{Convex hull}(\nabla f_k(z)\colon f_k(z)=f(z)).
   $$
3. $\|w\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^n|w_k|$ and $|w_k|=\max\{p\cdot w_k\colon p\in\{-1,1\}\}$.

**Addendum:** After one calculates the subgradient [(see here, p. 5)](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/01-subgradients_notes.pdf)
$$
\partial \|w\|_1=\{x\colon \|x\|_\infty\le 1,\ w^Tx=\|w\|_1\}
$$
the problem is LP
$$
\min_{x,t}\, t\qquad\text{subject to}\ -t\le x_i+y_i\le t,\ -1\le x_i\le 1,\ w^Tx=\|w\|_1.
$$

Comment: I know the sub-gradient set of  $L1$ norm. How to minimize on that set is my question. Sub-differential set (aka sub-gradient set) is as given by @Michael below.

Comment: @chandresh I have added few lines to the answer about that.