# Minimize $\|x\|_\infty$ such that $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have $A \in \mathbb{R^{n,m}}$ with $n\leq m$ and $b \in \mathbb{R^{n}}$. $A$ is of rank $n$ (maximal possible rank).

I'm looking for $x \in\mathbb{R^{m}}$ such that $Ax=b$ and for which $\|x\|_\infty$ is minimal.

Some looking around the Internet tells me the solution would be $x= (AA^T)^{-1}A^Tb$ if I were to be interested in minimizing $\|x\|_2$, but I'm really interested in minimizing $\|x\|_\infty$.

If that can help give a more detailed solution, the case I'm particularly interested in is $(n,m)=(3,4)$.

Do you see how to solve to this problem ?

Comment: What are you looking for?  A nice formula or an algorithm that gives you the answer?

Comment: I don't think that there will be a closed form solution as $||x||_{\infty}$ is not differentiable. But you should be able to get it with numerical scemes.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : ideally yes, a formula. If not possible, an algorithm.

Comment: @MrYouMath : yes, that's what I mean. On your second question, yes I edited it too after realizing I had it backwards.

Comment: A similar question was answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221188/l-infinity-norm-regularized-proximity-problem Just rewrite your problem as $\text{min } \| Ax - b\|_2 + \|x\|_\infty$

Comment: @dt688 Does that give the same solution? Presumably a $\varepsilon$ increase in the maximum component of $x$ could yield a more than $\varepsilon$ decrease in the first term. However, it can't increase by more than $\lambda \varepsilon$, where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$, so multiplying the second term by $\lambda$ should work.

Comment: @dt688 Well, the pointed solution is just out of reach for me. I just don't know most of the terms of the link (lsc ? Moreau decomposition ? Fenchel ?). I have to admit I'm hoping the specifics of my question (linear algebra) would help return a more specific, "simpler" answer.

Comment: This problem can be reduces to a linear programming problem. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407881/constrained-infinity-norm-minimization

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret yes, you are right. There should be a $\lambda$ term in front of the $\|x\|_\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\|x\|_\infty = \min_z \{z : -z \leq x_i \leq z \ \text{for} \ i = 1,\dots, m\}$. Therefore

$$\min_{\{x_i\}}\{\|x\|_\infty : Ax = b\} = \min_{\{x_i\},z}\{z : Ax = b, -z \leq x_i \leq z \}$$
This is a linear programming problem:

$$\min z \\ s.t. \ -z \leq x_i \leq z \\ \quad \sum_j A_{ij}x_j = b_i \tag{1}$$
In most cases (1) cannot be solved analytically, but can be easily solved numerically, even for very large problems.